# Creating a new dataframe to contain a section of 1 column from multiple csv files in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

So I am trying to create a new dataframe that includes some data from 300+ csv files.
Each file contains upto 200,000 rows of data, I am only interested in 1 of the columns within each file (the same column for each file)

I am trying to combine these columns into 1 dataframe, where column 6 from csv 1 would be in the 1st column of the new dataframe, column 6 from csv 2 would be in the 2nd column of the new dataframe, and so on up until the 315th csv file.

I dont need all 200,000 rows of data to be extracted, but I am unsure of how I would extract just 2,000 rows from the middle section of the data (each file ranges in number of rows so the same exact rows for each file arent necessary, as long as it is the middle 2000)

Any help in extracting the 2000 rows from each file to populate different columns in the new dataframe would be greatly appreciated.

So far, I have manipulated the data to only contain the relevant column for each file. This displays all the rows of data in the column for each file individually.
I tried to use the iloc function to reduce this to 2000 rows but it did not display any actual data in the output.

I am unsure as to how I would now extract this data into a dataframe for all the columns to be contained.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import itertools


#glob to get all csv files
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join('filepath/', "*.csv"))

#loop list of csv files
for f in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None)
    df.rename(columns={6: 'AE'}, inplace=True)
    new_df = df.filter(['AE'])
    

    
    print('Location:', f)
    print('File Name:', f.split("\\")[-1])
    print('Content:')
    display(new_df)
    print()
```

Comment: Once you have a df object, you can do df[ANY COLUMN NAME] = LIST. Therefore, you can get 2000 from one file maybe using df['csv1] = csv1_df[NEEDED COLUMN NAME][9000:11000]

Comment: How might I automate this to run through all the files and compile into the same list but remain in different columns?

Comment: What do you mean by compiling into the same list but remain in different columns? If you add each file sample to a column in the dataframe, you can access every column through the dataframe object

Comment: @CharlieBONS How might I add each file sample to a column in the dataframe? the code I have above displays the data from each file in different dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I am inferring that you have a number of different files in csv format, each of which has at least 2000 lines and 6 columns. You want to take the data only from the 6th column of each file and only for the middle 2000 records in each file and to put all of those blocks of 2000 records into a new dataframe, with a column that in some way identifies which file the block came from.

You can read each file using pandas, as you have done, and then you need to use `loc`, as one of the commenters said, to select the 2000 records you want to keep. If you save each of those blocks of records in a separate dataframe you can then use the pandas `concat` method to join them all together into different columns of a new dataframe.

Here is some code that I hope will be self-explanatory. I have assumed that you want the 6th column, which is the one with index 5 in pandas because we start counting from 0. I have also used `usecols` to keep only the 6th column, and I rename the column to an index number based on the order in which the files are being read. You would need to change this for your own choice of column naming.

I choose the middle 2000 records by defining the starting point as record `x`, say, so that `x + 2000 + x = total number of records`, therefore `x=(total number of records) / 2 - 1000`. This might not be exactly how you want to define the middle 2000 records, so you could change this.

`df_middles` is a list to which we append every new dataframe of the new file's middle 2000 records. We use `pd.concat` at the end to put all the columns into a new dataframe.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

# glob to get all csv files
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join("filepath/", "*.csv"))

df_middles = []

# loop list of csv files
for idx, f in enumerate(csv_files, 1):
    # only keep the 6th column (index 5)
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, usecols=[5])
    colname = f"column_{idx}"
    df.rename(columns={5: colname}, inplace=True)
    number_of_lines = len(df)
    if number_of_lines < 2000:
        raise IOError(f"Not enough lines in the input file: {f}")
    middle_range_start = int(number_of_lines / 2) - 1000
    middle_range_end = middle_range_start + 1999
    df_middle = df.loc[middle_range_start:middle_range_end].reset_index(drop=True)
    df_middles.append(df_middle)

df_final = pd.concat(df_middles, axis="columns")
```